# General equation of a translated and rotated torus

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, surfaces, rotations

every source I've found about [Tori describe the Torus equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html) as:

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} -R\right)^2 + z^2 = r^2$$

where:

- $R$ is the distance between the center of the hole and the center of the tube;
- $r$ is the radius of the tube.

By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1352920/578147) I can realize that this equation assumes that the origin of the $xyz$ system is the center of the hole.

Thus, what is the equation for a torus which is not in the origin? And how to derive the torus equation for a rotated torus like the ones in the following image?

[image: 3 tori rotated and translated fro the origin]

<strike>EDIT: I would appreciate if someone with enough reputation can create a "torus" tag and tag this question with it.</strike>

Comment: A “torus tag” is a little too specific. Torus’s are studied in analytical geometry and topology quite often - do one of those tags should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a year late but hopefully this helps someone. This answer is based on my own experiences in creating software that generates rotated and translated tori. This isn't specific to tori - for any shape you can rotate and then translate the point before applying the equation.

**Translational:**

$$(\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} - R)^2 + (z-c)^2 \leq r^2$$

where

- $R$ is the major radius, or 'the distance between the center of the hole and the center of the tube'.
- $r$ is the minor radius, or 'the radius of the tube'.
- $[a,b,c]$ is the center of the torus

**Rotational:**

For each $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ we can map $[x,y,z]^T \to H \cdot [x,y,z]^T $, where $H$ is a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions).

To make this an equation you could split the rotation matrix up. Lets say $H_0$ is the first row, $H_1$ the second, and $H_2$ the third. Let $p$ be $[x,y,z]^T$.

$$(\sqrt{(H_0 \cdot p)^2 + (H_1 \cdot p)^2} - R)^2 + (H_2 \cdot p)^2 \leq r^2$$

**Translational and Rotational:**

You'll need to apply the rotation first, then translate. This is because the rotation matrix will rotate about the *origin*. If you translate it first, the rotation will not be around the center of the torus.

The full equation would be

$$(\sqrt{((H_0 \cdot p) - a)^2 + ((H_1 \cdot p) - b)^2} - R)^2 + ((H_2 \cdot p) - c)^2 \leq r^2$$

where

- $R$ is the major radius, or 'the distance between the center of the hole and the center of the tube'.
- $r$ is the minor radius, or 'the radius of the tube'.
- $p = [a,b,c]$ is the center of the torus
- $H$ is the rotation matrix that rotates your torus

  - $H_0$ is the first row of $R$
  - $H_1$ is the second row of $R$
  - $H_2$ is the third row of $R$

Comment: Hi @Ysi, thank you for your answer. I'm looking forward to test it soon. I'll feedback you as soon as possible.