# about smooth manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x, y, z)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}\right)^2-4 R^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)
$$
and $R,r \in \mathbb{R} , 0<r<R$

now define :

$Z=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}  | f(x,y,z)=0\}$

(i)- Prove $Z$ is a smooth manifold.

(ii)-draw set $Z$ in $\mathbb{R^3} $.

(iii)- find coordinate charts on $Z$.

(iv) prove  $Z$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times S^1$.

for (i) i think we can use following theorem :

> theorem : if $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, $f: M \to N$ is a smooth map and $n \in f(M)$ is a [regular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)) for $f$, then $f^{-1} (\{n\})$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ of dimension $\dim M - \dim N$.

for (ii) we must compute $Z$ . i think  $Z=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}  | x^2+y^2=R^2,z^2=r^2\}$ so $Z$ is two circle with radios $R$ and $z=-r,+r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

$i).\ $ Fix an arbitrary $p\in Z$ and show there are no critical points for $f$ on $Z.$

$ii).\ $ Consider that  $\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}\right)^2-4 R^{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)=0\Rightarrow $

$z^2=\pm2R\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2-(R^{2}-r^{2})$ and compare with the equations and arguments of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352792/how-to-derive-the-3d-equation-of-a-torus).

$iii).\ $ From $i).,\ $ note that one of $\partial_x(p),\ \partial_y(p),\ \partial_z(p)$ is non-zero, say $\partial_x(p)$. Now, consider $\varphi:(x,y,z)\mapsto (f,y,z)$ defined in some $U(\subseteq \mathbb R^3)$-neighborhood of $p$ and show that $\varphi|_{U\cap Z}$ is a slice chart about $p\in Z.$

$iv).\ $ Apply $ii).$

Comment: .how we can show :  Fix an arbitrary $p\in Z$ and show there are no critical points for $f$ on $Z.$ ?

Comment: Calculate the partials and show they do not vanish all at once on any pt in $Z$.

Comment: I Calculate the partials , but i can't prove this.

Comment: Set them equal to zero and solve 3 eqns in 3 unknowns.